# Opening csv file with notepad with two different desktop running both windows gives different results

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, csv, notepad

Opening csv file with notepad with two different desktop running both windows gives different results

One of the desktop when opened, it's kind of lined nicely with newline, but somehow the other one opens without newline that it's all squished together.

Anyone has any idea how this can be dealt with?

For example, the one showing nicely

```
"A","B","C"
"D","E","F"
"G","H","I"
```

The other one would show

```
"A","B","C""D","E","F""G","H","I"
```

Exactly the same file.

Anyone know what I can do to the file to make the other machine read it nicely too?

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

Comment: Why the Excel tag?? -- are the lines of text longer than the width of the window?

Comment: Try turning on Word Wrap in the Format menu.

Comment: @teylyn opened the csv with excel which I forgot to mention.  In excel it looks fine (in the good looking desktop).  The other desktop does not have permission to get excel

Comment: @teylyn I just turned on word wrap, let's say ok that make it look better but the application I need to read the file won't read the word wrap.  It's acting as new line is not there unless I really used enter to break the line myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to upload data from the `.csv` file to the `.xlsx` file is:

1. Tab Data
2. Section Get & Transform Data
3. Click on From Text/CSV
4. Choose `.csv` file
5. Excel will open a pop-up window with the best data separation
6. You can choose the Character set - code page, Delimiter, or even transform data which brings you to all options about data.
7. Click on Load, data will be loaded inside Sheet.

Excel 365 Enterprise edition.

Comment: This worked great, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Are they both running the same version of Windows? Notepad received [an update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/extended-eol-in-notepad/) some time ago that let it supports MacOS (`CR`), Windows (`CR` `LF`), and Linux (`LF`) End of Line (`EOL`) sequences.

Maybe your file only has `LF` endings, and one machine can't interpret the EOL character correctly.

You could verify this by installing [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), opening the file in it, then go in "View > Show Symbol > Show End of Line" to see the type of EOL sequence used.

Comment: I won't be able to install additional software due to some restrictions, but that is nice to know.  They are not running the same version of windows